# Yii2 2amigos/yii2-leaflet-draw-plugin : how i can add searchbox

Tags: yii2, leaflet

im yii2 devloper ,  i  add  2amigos/yii2-leaflet-draw-plugin package for drawing polygon on myp ,i need to  add geoSearch on my map

-how  i can add searcbox (geaSearch  function) to my  leaflet map

this is  the code (GeoSearch )

```
 var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(map);

  var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

  searchControl.on('results', function(data){
    results.clearLayers();
    for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
    }
  });

setTimeout(function(){$('.pointer').fadeOut('slow');},3400);
```

where i have to  add this code  ? ! , i  add it directly on the form page (view file) but its not working  at all .

please if you  have idea about thi  or solution   ,  i really need it

thankyou advance

Comment: @IvanSanchez  is it  there no options to modifid or add searchbox on the package 2amigos/leaflet  ? ?

Comment: yes thats mayn  i  dont  know  why its closed  ??